# Saving drop down settings for Windows Application?

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5

I have a .Net 3.5 windows application with various drop down lists!

I want to be able save the choices the user has selected in the drop downs???

I had tried setting ApplicationSettings PropertBinding but this didn't work! is there something else I have to do? I was unable to select anything other that the first item in a drop down when I set this??

I am not sure how to Write to the app config file! is this what I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not save the user setting to a file ( any file, be it binary, flat or XML file), and when the drop down list is called, just call the `Load` function?

Here's [an example](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/07/use-doinstead-for-parameter.html) I did for saving and loading property grid information to a XML file. Hope it's useful.